# SageMath: Mod().sqrt() prefixed with "sqrt" string for a particular combination in Sagemath. Is this a bug?

Tags: cryptography, modulo, sage, largenumber

Using Sagemath 9.2 on Windows 10

`a1 =  9798722381116618056227637476565566484018606253194222755351973203508462742253522311154076194134700145275527578605535821781545038187843569198505993524407287520970070771172279404172004212310432500247465608472105231701909612623072343883942216806934904529600639676698348239426243771486521532222069409611514728756060897629936844695006373653175992634673678639333010508845045985607328371180356262460490393317997708599757357055386370808544031455931154122353547239678217006604692623467390849309525705453042722141078914816760002281629323554959490483823338710209710265138177331357093216148991708169324688688552846634664517554736`

`n = 27772857409875257529415990911214211975844307184430241451899407838750503024323367895540981606586709985980003435082116995888017731426634845808624796292507989171497629109450825818587383112280639037484593490692935998202437639626747133650990603333094513531505209954273004473567193235535061942991750932725808679249964667090723480397916715320876867803719301313440005075056481203859010490836599717523664197112053206745235908610484907715210436413015546671034478367679465233737115549451849810421017181842615880836253875862101545582922437858358265964489786463923280312860843031914516061327752183283528015684588796400861331354873`

`a2 =  Mod(a1, n).sqrt()`

I get the following

`sage: print(a2)`
`sqrt9798722381116618056227637476565566484018606253194222755351973203508462742253522311154076194134700145275527578605535821781545038187843569198505993524407287520970070771172279404172004212310432500247465608472105231701909612623072343883942216806934904529600639676698348239426243771486521532222069409611514728756060897629936844695006373653175992634673678639333010508845045985607328371180356262460490393317997708599757357055386370808544031455931154122353547239678217006604692623467390849309525705453042722141078914816760002281629323554959490483823338710209710265138177331357093216148991708169324688688552846634664517554736`

If you observe, a2 is prefixed with sqrt!

I don't see this with other roots, I calculated with Sage. What does this mean?

Is this a bug or does this have some other meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear `n` is prime (at least pseudo-prime):

```
sage: n.is_prime(proof=False)
True
```

Assuming it is, let us define the finite field in `n` elements:

```
sage: F = GF(n, proof=False)
```

and view `a1` as an element `A1` in `F`:

```
sage: A1 = F(a1)
```

Asking whether `a1` is a square modulo `n`
amounts to asking whether `A1` a square in `F`.

```
sage: A1.is_square()
False
```

It is not! So when we compute the square root of `A1`,
it has to be in a quadratic extension of `F`.

This is why when we ask Sage to compute this square root,
it gives it as a generator of that extension.

A natural name for this generator is "sqrt(n)",
which is what Sage uses.

Probably, when you computed other square roots,
they were square roots of numbers which were
squares modulo n, and therefore the square roots
could be computed in `F`, i.e. in `ZZ / n ZZ`,
without requiring a quadratic field extension.